# ng new give "npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY required sha1 but found sha512"

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to create a new project in Angular 7, but getting the below error.

> npm ERR! code EINTEGRITY
>   npm ERR! sha1-SKjl7xiAdhfuK14zwRlMNbQ5Ukw= integrity checksum failed when using sha1: wanted sha1-SKjl7xiAdhfuK14zwRlMNbQ5Ukw= but got sha512-3ds0bW0f5xtxepS3MKBqKiG2i93CTT5cG6vlfsoFDIps7lzcSnZweu3t15S90EacDpenHFyAQdpJlCaMpyLROA== sha1-X4ctB1ciOMPTjjyMj8IQXIHbMBU=. (197 bytes)

Tried every possible solution on my system, but none is helping me out.

Below is the list of solutions I have tried.

- nmp install latest
- clear cache
- remove node_modules
- force clear cache
- uninstall angular and reinstall angular

Comment: Please run these two commands and tell us the ouptput.
`node -v` to check your node version and `npm -v` to check your npm version. There may be a version mismatch

Answer (score 11):

These errors are sometimes due to caching or your **.lock** file.
So here are some steps you may follow to fix the issue.

- Remove node_modules `rm -rf node_modules`
- remove your `package-lock.json` file
- clear the cache. `npm cache clean --force`
- verify the cache `npm cache verify`
- Then run `npm install --registry https://registry.cnpmjs.org`

If it doesn't work try to update you package manager running

- `npm i -g npm`
- Then, run `npm install` again.

Comment: Hi @Ulrich

i tried this solution but it was not working

Comment: npm WARN tarball tarball data for https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-6.9.0.tgz (sha512-91V+zB5hDxO+Jyp2sUKS7juHlIM95dGQxTeQtmZI1nAI/7kjWXFipPrtwwKjhyKmV4GsS2LzJhrxRjGWsU9z/w==) seems to be corrupted.

Comment: Did you try to update your npm globally ? Are you on Linux, Mac or Windows ?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16 and have updated the npm globally

Comment: Try this one changing the registry `npm install --registry https://registry.cnpmjs.org`

Comment: ; cli configs
metrics-registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
scope = ""
user-agent = "npm/6.9.0 node/v11.12.0 linux x64"

; userconfig /home/webx/.npmrc
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"

; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /home/webx
; HOME = /home/webx
; "npm config ls -l" to show all defaults.

Comment: the radical solution would be to manually remove npm cache and uninstall node, angular-cli and npm before installing them again

Comment: its working in administrator but for other user its giving me this issue

Comment: Maybe you installed the npm as admin. That may be the reason of the issue.

Comment: i have used -g as a global .. can you suggest me on this

Comment: For installing npm, angular-cli and node thats right to use the `-g` option.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. It also fixed some dependency conflict errors.